# Flutter Firestore all delete Collection and Subcollection

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, collections

I want to delete the collection with many documents and subcategories in it. How can I do it?

[image: 1]

The code below didn't work. I tried many methods. I want to delete all information and subcollections in the collection.

```
AllDelete() async {
    user = await _auth.currentUser();

    final userRef = Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(user.uid).collection("SORU");
    userRef.getDocuments().then((snapshot) {
      snapshot.documents.forEach((doc) {
        doc.data.remove(1);
        print("IDLERRRR ${doc.documentID}");
      });
    });`
```

Answer (score 0):

The code didn't work means, how did you check ?
I suspect some of the collections got deleted some weren't.

> Note that delete is NOT an atomic operation in a document based NoSQL database like firebase and it's possible that it
> may fail after only deleting some documents.

**If you want anyway to try**, you can manually handle all the delete requests of different documents recursively using a cloud function shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/delete-collections?authuser=0#node.js)

But it is highly not recommended to do it from a web client, like Flutter.

From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data?authuser=0#collections)

> Deleting a collection requires coordinating an unbounded number of
> individual delete requests. If you need to delete entire collections,
> do so only from a trusted server environment. While it is possible to
> delete a collection from a mobile/web client, doing so has negative
> security and performance implications.

Cheers :)